# WebSphereUowTransactionManager returning null transactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, websphere, transactionmanager

I have a legacy code that use the TransactionManager to obtain access to the transaction to associate synchronization objects to the transaction afterCommit.

When I migrate to Spring 3, the recommended transaction manager to my solution is WebSphereUowTransactionManager, in truth, I feel that it is only a factory to the real Transaction Manager. But this transaction manager always return null in the method getTransactionManager().

I'm using EJB's 2.1 (legacy, remember?) with CMT.

My configuration is Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, Hibernate 3.6.8.Final, Websphere 6.1.0.43, my beans are:

```
<bean 
    id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />   


<bean 
    name="auditContextManager" 
    class="... my class ...">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <bean factory-bean="transactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

My hibernate configuration is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/ORDS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    ... too much mappings to show here ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my bean auditContextManager has always transactionManager set to null.

It seems to me that WebSphereUowTransactionManager do not expose Transaction Manager intentionally. Is this alright ?

There is any way so I can get the Transaction Manager ? Since WebSphereUowTransactionManager is not really the transaction manager, but only a transaction manager factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a factory for the `TransactionManager` but, as the name suggest, the `UOWManager`. It uses the Websphere native API for managing transactions (which has broader support for certain things than the plain JTA api).

So there isn't going to be a `TransactionManager` it will always be `null`.

Basically if you want the transactionamanager you will have to do a JNDI lookup.

Comment: Thank you guy. Do you know the right approach to do it with Spring 3?

Comment: Simply do a lookup for the transaction manager (`<jee:jndi-lookup id="jtaTxManager" jndi-name="java:comp/TransactionManager" />` not sure if that is the correct name but you should get the idea).

Comment: Great idea Deinum, but, it's Websphere, another world. In others J2EE servers this works fine, but not in Websphere. The only available names in java:comp namespace are: /ORB, /websphere/UOWManager, /websphere/ApplicationNotificationService, /websphere/AppProfile/TaskNameManager, /websphere/WorkAreaPartitionManager, /websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction, /websphere/UOWSynchronizationRegistry, /HandleDelegate, /UserTransaction.

Comment: I don't know the name in websphere but I assume there must be a normal JTA transaction manager available somewhere. Just figure out the correct name, it was merely a sample to give you the idea on how to do things.

Comment: I've read somewhere about "websphere do not export transaction manager".

Answer (score 0):

**com.ibm.ws.Transaction.TransactionManagerFactory** is the factory you should use to get the transaction manager .

Comment: com.ibm.ws.Transaction.TransactionManagerFactory is considered a product internal and is therefore not supported by application.